# How to get the string inside [[ string ]] inside a string ? (C#)

Tags: c#, string, parsing

As you have seen in C# a statement is inside braces as { }
Now what if we have a string that contains multiple strings inside [[ ]] these.

Sample input output:

```
string s = "this is the string I am talking about [[and the text inside]] but don't      forget about other [[ones like this]].";

string[] insideBrackets;

insideBrackets[0] will be **and the text inside**
insideBrackets[1] will be **ones like this**
```

Btw I have string split and indexOf but they are not working as well as I want.
Thank whoever answers, hope this gets thumbs up as its a good question :)

Comment: you can use `Regex` to get the string inside the bracket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Regex` for this.

```
string s = "this is the string I am talking about [[and the text inside]] but don't      forget about other [[ones like this]].";

var insideBrackets = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[\[(.+?)\]\]").Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                        .ToArray();
```