# Get string inside a splitted string from a MULTILINE text. C#

Tags: c#, regex

So I have this text file, which designed to look like as a table of data.
In this case. I only needed the computer name. Which was stored inside the 2nd vertical bar.

Here's the example of the text file:

```
2022-05-24 14:09:59 | Macbook1.local | Accepted | Authentication successful!
2022-05-24 14:09:59 | Macbook2.local | WrongCredential | Wrong credentials!
2022-05-24 14:09:59 | Macbook2.local | InvalidCSRF | Invalid CSRF-Token!
2022-05-24 14:09:59 | Macbook3.local | WrongCredential | Wrong credentials!
```

And here's how I wanted it to be outputted like:

```
Macbook1.local,Macbook2.local,Macbook3.local
```

It's similar to this: [How to get the string inside [[ string ]] inside a string ? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876385/how-to-get-the-string-inside-string-inside-a-string-c)
[I guess???] But in this case, there are more characters that are locked inside the character that defines other values. I hope I've summarized this clear enough.

Comment: `string.Join(",", File.ReadLines("path").Select(line => line.Split('|')[1].Trim()).Distinct())`

Comment: i am stupid, thanks a lot for that.